# Slow Performance when ORDER BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a project (Microsoft SQL Server 2012) in which I do need to store quite some data.
Currently my table does contains 1441352 records in total.

The structure of the table is as follows:

- RecordIdentifier (int, not null)
- GlnCode (PK, nvarchar(100), not null)
- Description (nvarchar(MAX), not null)
- VendorId (nvarchar(100), not null)
- VendorName (nvarchar(100), not null)
- ItemNumber (PK, nvarchar(100), not null)
- ItemUOM (PK, nvarchar(128), not null)

My table is indexed on the following fields:

- NonClustered - GlnCode, Ascending
- NonClustered - ItemNumber, Ascending
- NonClustered - ItemUOM, Ascending
- NonClustered - VendorID, Ascending
- Clustered - Unique (The above 4 columns together).

Now, when I'm writing an API to return the records in the table.
The API exposes methods and it's executing this query:

```
SELECT TOP (51) 
    [GlnCode] AS [GlnCode], 
    [VendorId] AS [VendorId], 
    [ItemNumber] AS [ItemNumber], 
    [ItemUOM] AS [ItemUOM], 
    [RecordIdentitifer] AS [RecordIdentitifer], 
    [Description] AS [Description], 
    [VendorName] AS [VendorName]
FROM [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE]
```

If I look at the performance, this is good.
But, this doesn't guarantee me to return always the same set, so I need to apply an `ORDER BY` clause, meaning the query being executed looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (51) 
    [GlnCode] AS [GlnCode], 
    [VendorId] AS [VendorId], 
    [ItemNumber] AS [ItemNumber], 
    [ItemUOM] AS [ItemUOM], 
    [RecordIdentitifer] AS [RecordIdentitifer], 
    [Description] AS [Description], 
    [VendorName] AS [VendorName]
    FROM [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE]
    ORDER BY [GlnCode] ASC, [ItemNumber] ASC, [ItemUOM] ASC, [VendorId] ASC
```

Now, the query takes a few seconds to return, which I can't afford.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm a mySQL guy but I'd imagine that sorting a large result on a 100 char varchar field would be pretty slow. You might want to experiment with adding an extra smaller varchar column that replicates the first few characters of that column, and sort on that. That's my guess. (edit) Additionally it's possible that since vendorID is only indexed locally this is causing some kind of push-down sort (we don't have that kinda thing in the versions I'm used to, but I hear it's nifty and potentially slow)

Comment: @DanielStackenland Even when adding an index on all the columns on which I'm applying sorting doesn't resolve the issue. Maybe I need to set some properties on the options or filter. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @joshstrike I cannot do that because that data is being imported from another source.

Comment: Can you reduce the columns in the order by clause and check the execution time. Lower the number of cols in order by clause, faster the query gets..

Comment: why can't you create NonClustered index on GlnCode with INcluding ItemNumber,ItemUOM,VendorID

Comment: Indeed, ordering one 1 single column does speed things up ,but it isn't what I need.

Comment: @mohan111 I can create that, but that doesn't speed up the query at all.

Comment: I hope these two cols are holding the numeric kind of data. Can you change the datatype of VendorId & Itemnumber to numeric such as Int, BigInt etc. Sorting would be faster on the numeric based cols.

Comment: @Complexity, try selecting SUBSTR(GlnCode,1,4) AS glnsub and then sort on that instead. Bet it's faster than sorting on the whole varchar data.

Comment: How come you have such a large PK, it looks like  RecordIdentifier could be the PK?

Comment: because here you are saying seperate clustered index for each column ..just create non clustered with GlnCode  include required columns with ASC order if you want remove nulls just try with filtered index

Comment: Are you sure the clusterd index is in the same order as the sorting?

Comment: I think I'll go with an option to add an extra field which I take the PK and use that field to provide an order.

Comment: @DanielStackenland Yes, I'm sure about that.

Comment: Post the query plan that the query uses. Then we'll see what index your query is using...

Comment: Can you try one thing. I'm not sure, how much logical I am going to be. `DROP` all existing indexes. Then execute your `SELECT` query and check the `execution plan`. It must show some missing indexes. Create those missing indexes and try again. Create primary key on some ID column preferably the first column that is going to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table index definitions are not optimal. You also don't have to created the additional individual indexes because they are covered by the Non Clustered Index.  You will have better performance when structuring your indexes as follows:

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE]
(
    RecordIdentifier int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    GlnCode nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    VendorId nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    VendorName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ItemNumber nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ItemUOM nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UniqueNonClusteredIndex-Composite2]
    ON [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE](GlnCode, ItemNumber,ItemUOM,VendorId ASC);

GO
```

Revised Query

```
SELECT TOP (51) 
    [RecordIdentifier] AS [RecordIdentitifer],
    [GlnCode] AS [GlnCode], 
    [VendorId] AS [VendorId], 
    [ItemNumber] AS [ItemNumber], 
    [ItemUOM] AS [ItemUOM],      
    [Description] AS [Description], 
    [VendorName] AS [VendorName]
    FROM [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE]
    ORDER BY [GlnCode], [ItemNumber], [ItemUOM], [VendorId]
```

First a key lookup will be performed on the Primary Key and then a Non Clustered Index Scan. This is where you want the majority of the work to be done.

Reference: 
[Indexes in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms175049.aspx)

Hope This helps